# Can I use a formula as a Table Name?

Tags: numbers

I would like to have a table name automatically generate when a root value is 
updated. For example, in my budget spreadsheet, I have `Groceries 11/07 -> 11/06`.
In a cell, if I have a cell `starting date` with value `11/01/2019`, I can use

```
=CONCATENATE("groceries ",MONTH($B$2),"/", DAY($B$2),"->",MONTH($B$2+6), "/", DAY($B$2+6))
```

to calculate the desired string without having to update it manually (when I make next month's spreadsheet, for example.) Is there a way to have a formula be the name of a table? Or should I just have an extra header row instead of displaying the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to make a table name the result of a calculation. You will need to use a table cell and hide the table name. Sounds like a good idea for a [feature request](https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html), though.